# PHP - http_get not sending http_origin

Tags: php, http-get

I am doing a http_get request like this...

```
$response = http_get("http://www.example.com/test.php", array("timeout"=>1), $info);
print_r($info);
```

But test.php has a request for $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] so fails. Is there a way to tell the http_get request to send this value over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set request headers with the *[options](http://php.net/manual/fa/http.request.options.php)* parameter of `http_get`

```
$response = http_get( "http://www.example.com/test.php",
                      array(
                          "timeout"=>1,
                          "headers"=>array(
                              "HTTP_ORIGIN" => "http://www.example2.com"
                          )
                      ), 
                      $info);
```